# User ID unregistered

Tags: discussion

Last week I have registered in serverfault as **Jaiganesh** and its worked fine, also I have posted 1 one question. Two days back I have logged by my gmail account & the user id has changed to **user1910258**. I am unable to edit/update my question. Please advise me.

Comment: This looks like the right one: http://serverfault.com/users/149600/jaiganesh

Answer (score 2):

This is easily fixable. You had an older unregistered account with the name to which the question was attributed. I merged the older user with your registered user, so you should now have ownership, and ability to edit the question.